# How to use two bits and transaction id in Device Check API IOS 11

Tags: ios, push-notification, ios11, uniqueidentifier

1. How to use two bits to identify unique device?
2. Will apple server change bit value automatically when app reinstalled in the device?
3. What is the purpose of `transaction_id`?

Actually, my use case is I want to replace FCM ID on my server when an app gets reinstalled on the same device.

Comment: Hi... I need to create device token with device check api and I am using swift and node. can you please tell me how do I achieve this? Thanks